# Видимость элементов, z-index

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, веб-дизайн

Подскажите, как сделать полосочку видимой? Рисунок - макет. У меня она практически не видна.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
.block2 {
height: 712px;
width: 100%;
background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(9, 5, 47, .85) 0%, rgba(49, 29, 94, .85) 100%), url(../img/block2.png);
}

.block2-content p {
font-size: 14px;
color: #f9f9f9;
letter-spacing: 1px;
font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
text-align: center;
padding-bottom: 20px;
background-image: url(../img/expertise-line.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center bottom;
}
```

Comment: покажите ваш html код.

Comment: да, код страницы бы непомешал

Answer (score 0):

Я бы порекомендовал заменить Ваш `background-image` на псевдо-элемент. И файлов на диске меньше, и один HTTP запрос к серверу сэкономите - оптимизация :)

```css
.block2 {
  height: 120px;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(9, 5, 47, .85) 0%, rgba(49, 29, 94, .85) 100%), url(../img/block2.png);
}

.block2-content p {
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #f9f9f9;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  position: relative;
}

.block2-content p:after {
  background: #ccc;
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: calc(50% - 50px);
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="block2">
  <div class="block2-content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
  </div>
</div>
```